# Liner Barcode scan from Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I need to implement the bar code read functionality in my asp.net application. This bar code is pre printed as liner bar code, now i want to read this bar code by the bar code reader in asp.net application. So can you please help for develop this code.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this JS code](http://manuels.github.io/unix-toolbox.js-exact-image/demo/), using this you could call the JS function from ASP and then return the values to your server side code and deal with it accordingly.

Comment: I want to read bar code using the bar code scanner. this js file read the barcode from the image. Am i right?